# How to solve this optimization problem with absolute values in the objective function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $y,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be $n$-dimensional vectors and $k>0$ be a positive constant. My goal is to minimize

$$k\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|-\alpha^Tx$$

with some linear constraints on $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Does anyone know how to put this problem in a standard form? Thanks.

Comment: It is already a convex optimization problem. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: You can express it as a LP.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you give me some more hints? I am not quite familiar with optimization.

Comment: @copper.hat If we double the variables by letting $|x_i-y_i|=u_i$, then we will have "or" in linear constraints, $x_i-y_i=u_i$ or $x_i-y_i=-u_i$. That's not a LP?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzIXT.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as an equivalent LP: 
$\min_{x,z \in \mathbb R^n} \{ k \sum_i z_i - \alpha^T x | x_i - y_i \le z_i, y_i-x_i \le z_i \}$.